# SSRS report takes a long time to appear but is quick to process

Tags: sql, sql-server, wpf, reporting-services

**EDIT**
I was working on a new report and I tried to make a blank one. Even this one takes ~12 seconds to appear. There's clearly something wrong but I'd like to try possible solutions you might have before reinstalling.

My application has a couple of SSRS reports. They're all simple tables listing the data. In the designer's preview tab, they all appear within 1-3 seconds. The SQL queries or Stored procedure they use all execute fast enough. The reports are hosted in a ReportViewer, inside a tabcontrol.

My problem is that most of these reports are going to be generated around 20 times in a row, each with different parameters, and it take a report 12 seconds or more to appear in the actual application, which is a big problem. What could be causing such a slowdown?

Here's a example of the simplest report I have, which still takes way too much time:

```
**Table Users**
Id uniqueidentifier PK
Name varchar(50)
Salary decimal
TimeInBank decimal
Enabled bit
```

The table has less than 100 rows, nothing special.
The query:

> Select * from Users where Enabled=1

In the execution log, this report has the following statistics:

```
TimeRendering: 79
TimeProcessing: 54
TimeDataRetrieval: 22
Status: rsSuccess
ByteCount: 5305
RowCount: 7
```

Nothing seems wrong with these numbers but it still takes at least 12 seconds from the moment I press the button to the moment I can see the report.

Comment: could it be related to this: http://rusanu.com/2009/07/24/fix-slow-application-startup-due-to-code-sign-validation/

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I get access to the server

Comment: Have you looked at IIS logs, the Server's EventViewer, and traced the requests with something like Fiddler yet? May be that your delay is somewhere in the transport.

Comment: I'll take a look at these but so far, the reports are slow even when I run the application on the server.

Comment: @FilipDeVos tried it, no differences

Answer (score 1):

If the data in your reports is not changing very often, you could consider caching the reports:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx

You still may want to figure out what the bottleneck is in the first place, but at least the viewers of the report won't have to wait in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the data change between each reports.